# Some @Override shows errors in Oracle Java but not in OpenJDK

Tags: java, android

In a repository that was created in Ubuntu Linux and compiled under OpenJDK 6, when implementing  LocationListener and SensorListener, adding the `@Override` tag above the inherited methods compiles fine.

But when the repo is cloned onto a Windows system with Oracle Java, some of the `@Override` generates errors. Example below: 
`The method onAccuracyChanged(Sensor, int) of type ExpeditionActivity must override a superclass method`

It seems that this error occurs only when you add `@Override` above a method that is inherited from implementing an interface. Adding `@Override` above a method inherited from a base class does not generate the error. This actually makes sense, because you are actually overriding the logic of the original method.

SO, is it syactically correct to write `@Override` above inherited interface methods?

Comment: In Java 1.5 you can use @Override to mark methods that are overriding super class methods. Since Java 1.6 you can mark methods with it that are implementing an interface, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Override` is limited to base class methods in JDK 5.

JDK 6 introduced the ability to apply `@Override` to interface methods.

Eclipse must be set to use JDK6/JDK6 language level to use `@Override` on interface methods.

To answer your question, "yes, if you're compiling under JDK 6+".

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm actually glad I encountered this error. It made me think about the differences between implementing an inherited abstract method and superseding a base class method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting it sometimes.
Not quite sure what the reasons for it are.

A few ways I found of fixing it. Maybe some of them would work for you

- Sometimes it helps simply deleting the method decleration and rewriting it.
- Make sure the parameters and return value are correct. For example, in Andrdid, when you extend `AsyncTask` you give the extended class 3 parameters, based on these paratmeters you need to override the methods with the correct parameters and return value.
- If the method are required for the interface/base class, try deleting the method. An error would appear under the interface/base class. Put your mouse cursor on it and select `Add Unimplemented methods` this would make eclipse add these methods and you would have to re-fill the body, but the error would disapper.

I do believe this is an Eclipse error, because removing the `@Override` annotation doesn't affect the code, the code compiles and runs correctly.

Good luck